# Duplicate Content Error by search console for online commerce site

Tags: google-search-console, duplicate-content

So I setup a website a few days ago and the Google search console gave the error: **Duplicate without user-selected canonical**

Now after reading, I found out that google asks to add canonical tags but I am not sure whether I add them on the home page or for product URLs as well. It just gives for the main page. Below is the screenshot of the GSC:

[image]

Comment: "Duplicate without user-selected canonical" isn't an error.  That is an informational message telling you that Google found multiple URLs for your site and chose to index a different one than the one you verified.   If you inspect your URL, what URL does Google say it duplicates?  How is that URL different from your preferred URL?

Answer (score 1):

It is best to have the `canonical` on each web pages and point it to itself.

For duplicate pages (or for the same page arrived via different urls), the canonical should point to your desired url.  Even then, it is a suggestion to Google that this is what you prefer.

For instance `https://www.example.com` and `https://example.com` are the same page, but are considered duplicates and the canonical must point to one or the other.  The exception is when you are rewriting or redirecting one url to the other.

Answer (score -2):

The canonical URLs should be defined for all your webpages.

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer! However, answers on Stack Exchange are expected to be a bit more substantive than this, explaining their reasoning in the context of the question. Please edit your answer to add some supporting details and/or reasoning. Thanks!